# ASP.NET: show or hide a link in a page according to location configuration in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an ASP.NET web site with some locations in the web.config file, e.g.

```
<location path="SomeWhere">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="some-role"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Then, in the master page for the site, I have a set of links, and I would like to show or hide some of the links according to the user's roles. I am currently doing this:

```
<% if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("some-role")) { %>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="SomeLink" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/SomeWhere/">Somewhere</asp:HyperLink>
<% } %>
```

I would like to avoid duplicating the role information in the web.config file and in the page code, and to replace the above check with something like

```
<% if (UserCanAccessLocation("Somewhere")) { %>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="SomeLink" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/SomeWhere/">Somewhere</asp:HyperLink>
<% } %>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i remember - to get SiteMapNode for that url and to use IsAccessibleToUser method to check.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll try it. Thanks.